# Flutter: Bluetooth permission is denied even if everything is checked manually on device (Android 13)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

im trying to allow my device (Android 13 Tablet) to scan for Bluetooth Devices.

In my AndroidManifest.xml i imported everything as mentioned in
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Declare the Bluetooth permissions your app needs -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <!-- These permissions are needed for Android 12 and above -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    
    <!-- If you target Android 12, but still need to support devices below Android 12, 
         you can conditionally include the location permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

My Code is the following:

...

```
void _startScan(BuildContext context) async {
    final PermissionStatus status = await _getBluetoothPermission();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _scanAndConnect(context);
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Bluetooth permission is denied')),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getBluetoothPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.bluetooth.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
      return status;
    } else {
      if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        openAppSettings(); // This will take the user to the app settings if permission is permanently denied
      }
      return await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    }
```

...

When i try to start the scan it always says permissions are denied, even when i check the permissions manually on the Settings of the Tablet it still says denied.

I dont know how to handle it any better. Do you have any advice?

Changing AndroidManifest.XML to different SDK Versions
Changing BuildGradle SDK Version to 33 instead of 33
Checking everything manually on the Hardware Side